# Restore Bucket on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am new and experimenting with Google Cloud Storage. I deleted my bucket while trying to learn how to restore my data back. I was under the impression that even if you delete a bucket it can be restored. But I am not finding that option on the console.

How can I restore the bucket I deleted on Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: Just keep in mind that object versioning does not protect you against a bucket deletion - so to be clear if you delete the bucket and have object versioning on you still will not be able to recover the bucket.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only option for restoring accidentally deleted data is to enable [object versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning). Unfortunately, that's not an option you can apply after having already deleted the objects.

Comment: reply by Caspianstrider: "Just keep in mind that object versioning does not protect you against a bucket deletion - so to be clear if you delete the bucket and have object versioning on you still will not be able to recover the bucket."